# How to catch page exit event of multipage control in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a multipage control on a userform. When the user navigates to a new page, I want the data on the current page to be saved to a database. The user can navigate between pages in various ways and I don't want to write a procedure for all of them. Is there an event I can use to reference the active page before the new page is selected?

I have looked at the Change event of the multipage control but if you reference multipage.selecteditem in there it refers to the new page. What I need is a BeforeChange event but there isn't one.

I have also looked at the multipage.exit event, but that triggers when the entire multipage control is exited, not just a page.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Use the `MultiPage1_Change` event.

If you have assigned a name to your Multipage, then you would change the subroutine from `MultiPage1_Change` (which is the default) to `YourMultiPageName_Change`.

for example I have one that is called "MultiPageBannerFilter".  I execute some code using this subroutine to trap the _Change event of this object.

```
Private Sub MultiPageBannerFilter_Change()

MsgBox "You have changed pages!", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Just put your code to save the info to database instead of the messagebox, and make sure the event subroutine is properly named and this should work.

**REVISION**

```
Public previousPage As String


Sub UserForm_Activate()
    previousPage = MultiPage1.SelectedItem.Name

End Sub

Private Sub MultiPage1_Change()

Dim currentPage As String
currentPage = MultiPage1.SelectedItem.Name

If Not currentPage = previousPage Then
    previousPage = currentPage
    '
    '
    MsgBox "Your Code Goes Here!", vbInformation
    '
    '
End If



End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think you understand how to apply this answer to your problem. You can declare some public variables to store what page is/was active, and detect changes that way. But in any case it needs to be handled with the `MultiPage_Change` event.  See revision, above.

Comment: Yes thanks I can see how to apply your solution (though the "Your Code Goes Here" line should be above the "previousPage = currentPage" line). I was hoping there was some other event that I wasn't aware of that could simplify. As I mentioned in my question I am aware of the MultiPage_Change event. I ended up placing my code in the click events of user navigations.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar challenge and came up with the below code.  You have to keep track of which Page you're on and use the Click event.  So, set the Multipage to a Page in the Initialize sub and set intPrevPage to the corresponding number.

```
Private Sub MultiPage1_Click(ByVal Index As Long)
    Select Case True
' If the click doesn't change the Page, then do nothing
        Case intPrevPage = MultiPage1.Value
' ValidForm is a function that validates data on previous
' Page if click changed the Page
        Case ValidForm
' If TRUE then capture current Page
            intPrevPage = MultiPage1.Value
            Call FormatPage
' If FALSE then return to previous Page
        Case Else
            MultiPage1.Value = intPrevPage
    End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

MultiPage1_Change event will only be fired if there is a page. Therefore, it's not necessary to detect the change and use the public variable "previousPage"

Private Sub MultiPage1_Change()
    Dim currentPage As String
    currentPage = MultiPage1.SelectedItem.Name
    MsgBox currentPage & " Selected!", vbInformation
End Sub